# How to improve my R syntax for ggplot2 to produce a line chart rather than a dotplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to R and I am plotting a chart using ggplot2. Running `head(mydata1)` gives me the following output of the structure of my dataframe:

```
 PropertyCode  Date        MthName      CY       TotalRN
     <chr>     <date>        <chr>   <chr>        <int>
     BLU       2015-01-01     Jan      CY 2015     146
     BLU       2015-02-01     Feb      CY 2015     278
     BLU       2015-03-01     Mar      CY 2015     143
     BLU       2015-04-01     Apr      CY 2015     365
     BLU       2015-05-01     May      CY 2015     198
     BLU       2015-06-01     Jun      CY 2015     114
```

Here is my ggplot2 syntax to plot a line curve:

```
ggplot(data=mydata1, aes(x=MthName, y=TotalRN, color=CY)) +
geom_line() +
geom_point()
```

The output (see image below) has 2 major problems:
(1) The x-axis is showing the MthName in alphabetical order rather than Jan, Feb, Mar....till Dec
(2) The plot looks more like a dotplot rather than a line curve

How do I correct for these 2 issues and make my plot look like the one shown further below (that one is from Excel using the same data)?

[image: Current R plot]

[image: Plot in Excel using same data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to convert your `Date` column to `Date` format and then try the following:

```
mydata1$Date = as.yearmon(mydata1$Date)

library(lubridate)
ggplot(data=mydata1, aes(x=month(mydata1$Date, label=TRUE, abbr=TRUE),
                    y=TotalRN, group=CY, color = CY)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("Month name")
```

Comment: My Date column has already been converted. I simply want the MthName to appear on the x-axis (like the second chart shown in my post)

Comment: I think my edited code does what you want (gotta have `scales` library)

Comment: I get the following error message:
Error in check_breaks_labels(breaks, labels) : 
  could not find function "date_format"

Comment: Should I load a specific library to use that function?

Comment: Yes, `scales`. But I'm having second thoughts because your `Date` column may have `2016` ... Will get back in a mom

Comment: Doesn't  `color = CY` also need to go into `aes()`?

Comment: Another way to get the months right would be to turn them into an ordered factor.

Comment: `fill` is inside, `color` is outside AFAIK

Comment: I have progressed a little with @AK88 help but I am now facing the issue that the plots for 2015 and 2016 are showing next to each other on the chart. I need them to look like the second chart in my post (that is, on top of each other).

Comment: @AK88 Sorry I was away from the computer. I am bit confused with the zz part. Do you mean I need to add this to my dataframe?

Comment: Edited out the parts that you don't need. It should work now, but you need to call `lubridate` package.

Comment: @AK88 Fantastic! Exactly what I needed. :-)